# Recommendations for cross-language, secure encryption

Tags: java, php, .net, encryption, password-encryption

I'm working on this what I hope to be my degree project since we have to do one over here to get that lame degree, anyway, I have a SOAP server, a PHP server and hopefully a Java application and an Android App, and maybe just maybe a .NET application, now my problem like you have probably guessed, that I'm clueless when it comes to encrypting, and not going to encrypt almost everything, but a password in the data base has to be encrypted no matter what, now I know MD5 is neat to use but has no security into it there are even some websites and a PHP function to decrypt it in a heart beat and so is SHA1. The reason I've mentioned those two is that I did some research and it lead me to the possibility of simply use those in all different languages and that's what I'm looking for (the possibility of easily deploy the encrypting process in any language I'm going to use) so can you recommend an encrypting method that does that?

ALSO, I have done some research and found that adding things to the encrypted string is good (salting) so I would be thankful if you guys mention some salting techniques in your answer all along with other techniques and a slight idea of the use of the encrypting functions (which are to replace md5 and sha1) in Java and PHP.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: Security is _hard_.  You need to learn a lot more before you start this.  For example, you need to learn the difference between encryption and hashing.  http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html

Comment: Thank you very much it has came clear to me that I need more research 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This might be better on security.stackexchange.com. Cryptography isn't really a field where anyone can tell you the perfect way to do everything. You need to do a lot of research on your own. However, I will suggest bcrypt for hashing your passwords. SHA-1 is probably fine as well. Bcrypt is a slower algorithm (good for password protection because it takes longer to brute force). Also, definitely salt the password before hashing. There should be available libraries in most languages. Obviously you'll need to use HTTPS as well, otherwise your users will transmit passwords in the clear.

Comment: Thank you, although I guess the many down ratings should tell me this is the wrong place to ask the question.
Again though thank you for being the only one to answer and for giving me some info :)

Comment: No; SHA1 is not fine.

Comment: Iterated SHA-1 (say 10000+ iterations) is okay, single iteration SHA-1 is not. Still it's better to use a standard construction, such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt.

Comment: @SLaks I wouldn't really recommend it but my research shows that with strong (non dictionary based, proper length, etc) passwords it is still secure enough for most uses... if you disagree please show why. Yes it is fast to brute force, but would still take too long for strong passwords, even with GPU based hashing assuming 4 billion attempts per second (which is higher than any GPU I know of), and a "perfect" efficiency distributed algorithm to distribute the brute force attack across hundreds of GPUs.